# Unpolarized muon decay rate and Feynman diagram trick

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, electroweak, nuclear-physics

In class, while evaluating the unpolarized muon decay rate, in the Fermi theory (low energy limit) we got the result for the matrix element

$$\frac{G^2_F}{2}\text{tr}\left[\gamma^\rho(1-\gamma_5)(\not p_\mu+m_\mu)\gamma^\sigma(1-\gamma_5)(\not p_{\nu_\mu}+m_{\nu_\mu})\right]\text{tr}\left[\gamma_\rho(1-\gamma_5)(\not p_{\nu_e}-m_{\nu_e})\gamma_\sigma(1-\gamma_5)(\not p_e+m_e)\right] $$

which is fine and i can understand. But soon after the professor said that we could get the same result by easily manipulating the Feynman diagram (he called them Curkosky rules) were he practically closed all the lines in the following manner

[image: Notes diagram]

Then just by tracing over the fermion lines, we get the same result.

Searching on the web for this said "Cutkosky rules" i found many results on the possibilty of cutting diagrams, but I didn't get anything out of it. Moreover I cannot understand why he put a propagator joining the two fermion loops, and I do not recall him saying anything more than the note i wrote beside it.

I know that probably there'll be a lot to say, but I would really appreciate if anybody could shine some light on what was done during this lesson and why. If somebody has some literature, i would really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you search for "Cutcosly" on this site? The traces are not hard to work out. A cut propagator is the very δ function in Lorentz indices. But you are really not providing enough information: you are just asking for a clearer lecture.

Comment: difficult names ,it seems to be  Cutkosky,and yes, there is a question-answer here